# willChangeValue equivalent for deleted entities?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

How do I get my entities to notify views when they are deleted the same way that `willChangeValue` notifies views when one of their attributes changes?

I'm using this code:

```
override public func willChangeValue(forKey key: String) {
    super.willChangeValue(forKey: key)
    self.objectWillChange.send()
}
```

This works fantastic for when the value of an entity attribute changes. The problem is that when an entity is deleted, the views don't seem to acknowledge that the entity has been deleted. I have to refresh the views for the changes to appear.

What is the equivalent of `willChangeValue` for deleting entities? Something like `willDelete` that I can use to push that update to views?

Also, I tried using `if (entity.isDeleted)` in my code and it seems to have no effect either.

Comment: The reason is rather in code of showing view. Could you post code of view which is not updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this pushes any changes or actions to views when managedObjectContext.save() is called, which resolved my issue:

```
public override func willSave() {
    super.willSave()
    self.objectWillChange.send()
}
```